# What could have possibly gone wrong? fopen bug

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have the following snippet of code at the beginning of my program:

```
printf("Starting extraction of file %s \n", tarName);

// Open the tarFile
FILE* tarFile = fopen(tarName, "r");
if(tarFile == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

// Read nFiles
printf("Reading header...");
...
```

When I execute it from the terminal I get the following output:

```
Starting extraction of file test.mytar
```

And then the program freezes, apparently never reaching the second `printf`.

`test.mytar` is an existing file in the same folder as my executable, and this is the same folder from where I am executing the terminal.

The file was created by me byte a byte, so it could possibly be violating file conventions I am not aware of.

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: Add a print statement just after `fopen` and before the if. Is it printed?

Comment: You should also show how the function is called and the code executed when the function returns

Comment: ... and have a `\n` in **all** `printf`

Comment: @4386427 `\n` flushing the `stdout` buffer is platform-specific.  The proper way to ensure the buffer is flushed is to either disable buffering, explicitly set line-buffering, or actually flush it.

Comment: @ChrisTurner turns out you are right! I was mistaken on where the bug was due to the confusing flush behavior

Comment: @AndrewHenle For a terminal (which I assume there), I think it does

Comment: @4386427 Per **7.21.3 Files**, paragraph 3, of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "Support    for    these    characteristics    is
**implementation-defined**, and may be affected via the
`setbuf`
and
`setvbuf`
functions."  Just because Linux line-buffers `stdout` when it's a terminal doesn't make that a universal truth.

Comment: @Jsevillamol running your code in a debugger would have shown you that it went past the `printf` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, two things may happen.

a) the fopen fails (IO error, permission denied, missing file, ...). To know the exact cause, you need to print the `errno` (or `GetLastError()` on Windows) :

```
if(tarFile == NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

b) the fopen succeeds but `printf("Reading header...");` does not show up anything because the message is buffered and not yet printed. To correct this, you can generally add a `'\n'` at the end of the message.